# How to rewrite date in desired format?

Tags: postgresql

Dates comes to me as strings like that '19901226'. But my db waits for '26.12.1990'. How to change it? I know that I need regular expression but never worked with them.

Comment: date('d.m.Y',strtotime($YOURVAR)) ?

Comment: Can you use php or is it only in postgresql ?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question and the INSERT query you are using. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it odd that your database expects a non ISO format date, but here goes:

```
echo date_create_from_format("Ymd","19901226")->format("d.m.Y");
```

Echos:

> 26.12.1990

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cd0c79eef6fb81a4e55cf314e7e8a9ff7934ada8